# WPF Listview databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I have a list view that has a column databound to a list.Count see below:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Contacts" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Contacts.Count}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Notes" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Notes.Count}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

The List implements INotifyCollectionChanged. But when I add an item to the list the listview column does not get refreshed. am I doing something wrong in my binding? I can do the following:

```
    void _Contacts_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("Contacts");
    }
```

Which basically raises the PropertyChanged event of the collection. This forces wpf to rebind, but I would rather not have an abundance of events flying through my code(especially the unnecessary ones).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while you raise a property changed for Contacts, you do not raise an event for the Count property..

You can solve this with

```
OnPropertyChanged("Count")
```

in your list, since your list implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can derive from ObservableCollection instead.  It has all the change notification code built into it and could save you some time in the long run.

Comment: Problem is I added some properties to the collection class that I need for databinding.

Comment: The ObservableCollection is built for databinding.  Additionally, you can easily derive from it to add additional functionality if needed.